# Having OIDC error 401 while user is not logged in

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, backend, openid-connect

```
@routes.route('/add_user', methods=['POST'])
@oidc.accept_token(True)
def add_user():
       xxx
```

I was trying to build user sign up function and get error 401 unauthorized when try to call above endpoint (backend). Confirmed that ** @oidc.accept_token(True) ** causing the error because the call request does not have access token (OAuth), which because user is not logged in.

```
'POST /add_user HTTP/1.1' 401
```

I tried commented out the line and it worked, but I prefer not to make the endpoint public otherwise people could flood the application using this user creation.

What could be the solution here? or I should say are there other authorization for user creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you *have* to make it public if you want unauthorized users to create an account.

Comment: thanks for the response. So would the hazard that I mentioned actually an issue if the application go live? Because seems this user creation would be accessible to all the port that listen to this url.

Comment: It depends on what the goal is. Anyone can make accounts so it can be a good practice to not give newly created accounts rights. You can do this by enforcing email verification and adding a captcha. Also a mechanism which disallows creation of an unreasonable amount of accounts from the same IP can help a lot. Note that the last one will only work with reverse proxies that also pass on the ip address. (e.g. free tier of cloud flare doesn't do this)